# R ggplot timeseries plot, single line, color by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a working plot of some time series data. Over the course of three years I have a value to plot. Looking at the plot, I would like to have each year plotted as a different color. In my data.frame I created a factor of Year. How can I use this to change the color?

> ```
>  head(wf)
>        Date Year Gals Days  GpD    GpM
>  2016-10-21 2016  6.0    1  6.0  186.0
>  2016-10-22 2016  6.0    1  6.0  186.0
>  2016-10-23 2016 12.4    1 12.4  384.4
>  2016-10-24 2016 26.8    1 26.8  830.8
>  2016-10-25 2016 33.3    1 33.3 1032.3
>  2016-10-26 2016 28.3    1 28.3  877.3
>  nrow(wf)   626
> ```
>
> Here is the basis of my code that works for a single color...

```
  myscat<-ggplot(wf, aes(x=Date, y=Gals)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels="%b-%y", date_breaks="1 month",expand=c(0,0),  position = "top") +
  geom_line(aes(lty = "Gals", color = "Gals")) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(wf$Gals), linetype = "Mean", color = "Mean"), size=1) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = median(wf$Gals), linetype = "Median", color = "Median"), size = 1) +
  scale_linetype('Water Usage', labels = labels) +
  scale_color_manual('Water Usage', values=c('Gals'='dodgerblue2', 'Mean'='red', 'Median'='orange'),
                 labels = labels) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,5,10,15,20,25,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100), 
                minor_breaks =seq(5,10,5), limits=c(0,100),expand=c(0,0)) +
  ggtitle( "Daily Water Usage", subtitle=subtext )+
  xlab("") + ylab("Gallons per Day") + #labs(title="Daily Water Usage") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),   plot.subtitle=element_text(family="Comic Sans MS")) +
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(),   legend.position = c(.975, .975),
   legend.justification = c("right", "top"), legend.box.just = "right",
   legend.box.margin = margin(3,3,3,3)) + mytheme02 +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
   panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
   panel.grid.major.x = element_line(size = .5, color = "lightgrey", linetype="dashed"))+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.75,0.5,0.25), "cm"))+

  geom_hline(mapping=NULL, yintercept=minors, colour="lightgrey", linetype="dashed", size = .5)+
  annotate("rect", xmin=wf$Date[1], xmax=wf$Date[nrow(wf)], ymin=5, ymax=20, alpha=0.1, fill="lightgrey") 
  print(myscat)
```

This produces:

[image]

I tried to color="Year" and Year is a factor ->{2016, 2017, 2018} with no success. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify aesthetics in the inital `ggplot` call. Try this:

```
ggplot(wf, aes(x=Date, y=Gals, group = Year, colour = Year)) +
  geom_line()
```

---

EDIT:

Example data:

```
wf <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17095, 17096, 17097, 17098, 17099, 17100, 17095,
                                    17096, 17097, 17098, 17099, 17100, 17095, 17096, 
                                    17097, 17098, 17099, 17100, 17095, 17096, 17097, 
                                    17098, 17099, 17100), class = "Date"), 
                 Year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
                                  .Label = c("2016", "2017", "2018"), class = "factor"), 
                 Gals = c(6, 6, 12.4, 26.8, 33.3, 28.3, 6, 28.3, 33.3, 6, 26.8, 12.4, 
                          33.3, 28.3, 26.8, 6, 12.4, 33.3, 6, 26.8, 6, 12.4, 28.3, 6), 
                 Days = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                 GpD = c(6, 6, 12.4, 26.8, 33.3, 28.3, 6, 6, 12.4, 26.8, 33.3, 28.3, 
                         6, 6, 12.4, 26.8, 33.3, 28.3, 6, 6, 12.4, 26.8, 33.3, 28.3), 
                 GpM = c(186, 186, 384.4, 830.8, 1032.3, 877.3, 186, 186, 384.4, 830.8, 
                         1032.3, 877.3, 186, 186, 384.4, 830.8, 1032.3, 877.3, 186, 
                         186, 384.4, 830.8, 1032.3, 877.3)), 
            .Names = c("Date", "Year", "Gals", "Days", "GpD", "GpM"), 
            class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Plot call:

```
ggplot(wf, aes(x=Date, y=Gals, group = Year, colour = Year)) + # Specifies colour inside aesthetics
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('dodgerblue2', 'red', 'orange')) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(wf$Gals)), colour = "pink", size=1) # <- Colour outside aesthetics
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but I used G_T's answer to post with some formatting what I received when running the answer...DeS

Comment: The above answer will plot `Gals` in a different colour for each year as the question asked. The error you receive is because your incorrect use of formatting. Since the colour of `Gals` is dependent on what is in the `Year` column that should be controlled by aesthetics. Since things like your horizontal lines are not dependent on the original data frame you should NOT specify them in the aesthetics. See my edited example.